# PowerDNS master-slave configuration issue

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, mysql, powerdns

On my master node of the 2-node PowerDNS cluster I have in my test environment to find all ins-and outs to deploy to production im getting the following error in the logs:

```
Request to queue notification for domain 'domain.example' was processed, but no valid nameservers or ALSO-NOTIFYs found. Not notifying!
```

This has something to do with the NS / A records on that domain only I cannot find what I have to do at this point, seems that my configurations are correct.

Master config:

```
allow-axfr-ips=10.10.30.32
master=yes
slave=no
```

Slave config:

```
allow-axfr-ips=10.10.30.31
master=no
slave=yes
```

On the slave node I also added the following record in the database:

```
MariaDB [powerdns]> select * from supermasters;
+-------------+--------------------+---------+
| ip          | nameserver         | account |
+-------------+--------------------+---------+
| 10.10.30.31 | ns2.domain.example | admin   |
+-------------+--------------------+---------+
```

I personally think it has something to do with the database, as I read in the documentation:

> • The nameservers have to be set up correctly as NS domain records i.e. deﬁning a NS and A record for eachslave.
>
> • Master/Slave state has to be conﬁgured on a per domain basis in the
>    domains
>    table. Namely the
>    type
>   column has to be either
>    MASTER
>    or
>    SLAVE
>    respectively and the slave needs a comma separated list of master node IP addresses in the
>    master
>    column in the
>    domains
>    table.

But I do just not understand what it's trying to say. Anybody an idea?

EDIT:

On my slave server there was a faulty record in the domains table, which led the slave to send the request to the wrong server like this:

```
Apr  8 08:56:03 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[2582]: While checking domain freshness: Query to '10.10.30.32' for SOA of 'ns2.domain.example.' did not return a SOA
Apr  8 09:02:12 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[2582]: message repeated 3 times: [ While checking domain freshness: Query to '10.10.30.32' for SOA of 'ns2.domain.example.' did not return a SOA]
```

After I changed the ip to .31 I got the following errors:

Master:

```
Apr  8 10:07:45 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[11803]: AXFR of domain 'ns2.domain.example' initiated by 10.10.30.32
Apr  8 10:07:45 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[11803]: AXFR of domain 'ns2.domain.example' allowed: client IP 10.10.30.32 is in allow-axfr-ips
Apr  8 10:07:45 hfr-nl-dns01 pdns_server[11803]: AXFR of domain 'ns2.domain.example' failed: not authoritative
```

slave:

```
Apr  8 10:07:45 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[2737]: Initiating transfer of 'ns2.domain.example' from remote '10.10.30.31'
Apr  8 10:07:45 hfr-nl-dns02 pdns_server[2737]: Unable to AXFR zone 'ns2.domain.example' from remote '10.10.30.31' (resolver): AXFR chunk error: Server Not Authoritative for zone / Not Authorized
```

EDIT 2: master database records, seen with the IP here, tried it also with the hostname of the nameservers which are defined in the /etc/hosts file.

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+----------+-----------+------+
| id | domain_id | name               | type | content                                                                          | ttl  | prio | disabled | ordername | auth |
+----+-----------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+----------+-----------+------+
| 14 |         5 | domain.example     | NS   | 10.10.30.31                                                                      | 3600 |    0 |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
| 15 |         5 | domain.example     | NS   | 10.10.30.32                                                                      | 3600 |    0 |        0 | NULL      |    1 |
```

Comment: I edited the post, came a bit further but still falling back to the same kind of issue, no syncing between the master and slave

Comment: Nope, after a reinstall I am back at the error `no valid nameservers or ALSO-NOTIFYs found. Not notifying!`. I know it has something to do with the NS records in the master node but it seems to be correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this part out for anyone who's wondering:

• The nameservers have to be set up correctly as NS domain records i.e. deﬁning a NS and A record for eachslave.

This is meant by the domain name that the domain servers are supposed to be hosted on; ns1.example.com / ns2.example.com. Add an A record with the public IP the server is being hosted on and a NS record that is pointing towards that A record.